# Is it possible to run Oracle on Windows XP without admin rights?

Tags: windows, oracle, windows-xp, admin

I have shared computer, where admin install Oracle XE. But I cannot e.g. create new user, because I have not rights in OS, afaik.
In Oracle documentation written that DBA should be member of administrator group.
Does exists way that I can manage local instance XE without admin rights?
I need start/stop database, connect/disconnect, kill session etc. It is need for test my Java application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an OS user with admin right (once Oracle is installed and running).

Just connect as SYSDBA then you can create new Oracle users and manage the complete database..

(I do that on XP as well - working with regular user, but connecting as SYSTEM or SYS with the SYSDBA role if I need to configure something in Oracle)

Answer (score 1):

> Does exists way that I can manage local instance XE without admin rights?

Probably not ... if that's what the Oracle documentation says.

A sensible strategy would be to discuss your problem with the admins.  Point out that it makes it difficult for you to do your job if you don't have access rights.  If they won't grant you system Admin rights, ask them to suggest alternatives that will allow you to do your job.

It may be simply that they need to grant you additional rights in Oracle.

Comment: I didn't know the OS rights were relevant at all. Oracle XE provides a web console that runs as LOCAL_SYSTEM by default :-?

Answer (score 1):

How about *getting* admin rights in a Virtual Machine? See virtualbox.org.

Answer (score 1):

From XE manual [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/users_secure.htm#CHDGFBAJ) :

*" On each platform, if the OS authentication user group does not already exist, it is automatically created when you install Oracle Database XE. In addition, upon installation on the Linux platform, the user account oracle is automatically created and placed in the dba group. Upon installation on the Windows platform, the user performing the installation is automatically added to the ORA_DBA group. On both platforms, you can add other host users to the OS authentication user group to enable them to connect to the database with the SYSDBA privilege. "*

Since installation on windows needs admin user which I assume you are not, so it renders the automatic addition of that admin user to ORA_DBA group useless for you.

So what your admin can do immediately after XE installation on this shared machine is just **add** your **non-admin OS user** (local or domain level, whatever) **to** the newly created OS local group **"ORA_DBA"**. Once this is done, you can simply open the sqlplus prompt and connect with SYSDBA privilege using your own non-admin user in future:

```
connect / as sysdba
```

However, you will still not be able to restart the Oracle service or the TNS listener, even if you are in the ORA_DBA group.